# How to create formControlName dynamically in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-controller, formarray

I want to create **formControlName** dynamically, here is my code in component,

> **CONTROLER CODE**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.rForm = this.fb.group({
     question_type_id: this.fb.array([]),
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < this.getQuestionsType.length; i++) {
     const control = <FormArray>this.rForm.controls['question_type_id'];
     control.push(this.initAddress(i));
  }
}

initAddress(i) {
  var ans = "is_answer_"+i;

  return this.fb.group({
    ans: ['']
  });
}
```

So I want **formControlName** Like this,

```
is_answer_0
is_answer_1
is_answer_2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In es6 objects can be created with [computed keys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer). So let's use it:

```
initAddress(i) {
  var ans = "is_answer_" + i;

  return this.fb.group({
    [ans]: ['']
    ^^^^^
  });
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/RHys2biiHIziGScSeeGd?layout=1)**

You should be aware that if typescript has target es5 then it will be tranpiled to something like:

```
var controlConfig = {};
controlConfig[ans] = [''];
```

So it's your second option to go

Answer (score 2):

Try code below. It certainly works !

```
ngOnInit() {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.getQuestionsType.length; i++) {
    <FormArray>this.rForm.get('question_type_id').push(new FormControl("is_answer_"+i));
  }
}
```